# If $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies an identity $\eta$, then every **commutative** ring satisfies $\eta$? And related questions.

Tags: logic, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, universal-algebra

Assume all rings have unity and that ring homomorphisms preserve unity.

Now by general principles, if every *free* object in the category of rings satisfies an identity $\eta$, then every *object* in the category of rings satisfies $\eta.$ However, its not the case that if the free ring on the empty set of generators (namely $\mathbb{Z}$) satisfies an identity $\eta$, then every ring satisfies $\eta$. In particular, take $\eta$ to denote commutativity.

**Question 0.** Is it true that if $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies an identity $\eta$, then every **commutative** ring satisfies $\eta$?

**Question 1.** Is there an accepted terminology for algebraic theories $T$ such that letting $Z$ denote the initial $T$-algebra, the following holds? "For all identities $\eta$ in the language of $T$, it holds that if $Z$ satisfies $\eta$, then every model of $T$ satisfies $\eta$."

**Question 2.** Is there a good characterization of such theories $T$?

Comment: Please write down any interesting identity in $\mathbb{Z}$ ... (or $\mathbb{Z}[x]$).

Comment: Well, if $Z$ is empty (i.e. $T$ has no constants) then every equation is trivially satisfied, including the inconsistent equation $x = y$.

Comment: As for question 0, it suffices to verify the following: if a (multivariable) polynomial vanishes at all integer points, then it is the zero polynomial. This can be done by induction.

Comment: @user18921: Do you think this is an *interesting* identity?

Comment: Is it even true in $\mathbb Z$? :)

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld, lol yeah I wrote it wrong. The correct statement of the mediality of $(-)$ is of course $(x−y)−(x′−y′)≡(x−x′)−(y−y'),$ and this is certainly true in any Abelian group, so it is true in every ring, and hence true in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, well I don't know what you consider interesting. Here's another identity that I find cool: $(x+y)(x-y) \equiv x^2-y^2$. This holds in any commutative ring, and therefore in $\mathbb{Z}$. Another good one is the Binomial theorem, which is actually a set of identities: $(x+y)^n \equiv \sum_{n=0}^n{n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^k.$ Once again, this holds in any commutative ring.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, I didn't see your second comment before I posted my answer, or I would have given you credit. As for your first question, the identity $x = y$ isn't inconsistent, it just implies any model has size $0$ or $1$. In fact, an algebraic theory with no constants satisfies the condition in the question if and only if it is trivial in the sense that every model has size $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 0:** Every identity in the language of rings is equivalent to one of the form $p(\overline{x}) = 0$, where $p(\overline{x})\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ for some $n$. So the question amounts to: if a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is $0$ at all points of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, is the zero polynomial?

The answer is yes. There are fancy ways to see this, but one can prove it by a simple induction. It's clearly true for polynomials in $0$ variables (which are just integers). Now suppose $p(\overline{x})\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, $n\geq 1$, and $p\neq 0$. Rewrite $p$ as a polynomial in $x_n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}]$:  $$p(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i = 0}^d q_i(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})x_n^i.$$
Since $p\neq 0$, $q_i\neq 0$ for some $i$. By induction, there are some $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ such that $q_i(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}) \neq 0$. But then $p(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},x_n)$ is a nonzero polynomial in one variable, $x_n$. A nonzero polynomial can have at most finitely many zeros in an integral domain, so there is some $a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},a_n)\neq 0$, and we're done.

**Questions 1 and 2:** If we have an algebraic theory $T$ and a collection of models $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that whenever an identity holds in all $A_i$, it holds in every model of $T$, we say that $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ *generate* the variety of models of $T$. This is equivalent to saying that every model of $T$ is a quotient of a subalgebra of some product of $(A_i)$s, by Birkhoff's theorem. So you're asking about varieties of algebras which are generated by the initial algebra, which can be characterized as those for which every algebra is a quotient of a subalgebra of a power of the intial object. I'm not sure how satisfying this characterization is, though...

By the way, it's nice to observe what this representation amounts to in the case of commutative rings: Given an arbitrary ring $R$, we can choose a set of generators in order to write it as a quotient of some free commutative ring $F$. Now we want to embed $F$ in a power of $\mathbb{Z}$. We can do this as long as for each nonzero element $f\in F$, there is a map $\phi_f:F\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with $\phi(f)\neq 0$. The product of all these maps $\phi_f$ will be an embedding $\phi:F\rightarrow \prod_{f\in F\setminus\{0\}}\mathbb{Z}$. So what's $\phi_f$? $f$ is a polynomial in finitely many variables, so as we saw above there's some tuple of elements from $\mathbb{Z}$ on which it's not $0$. Map $F$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ by sending the relevant variables to this tuple and all the others to $0$.